# React: How to store an array of objects inside an array from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that contains an array of objects, for example:

```
[
    {"name": "Timothy", "age": 14},
    {....},
    {....},
    ...
]
```

I want to create an array, e.g. `people`, and store basically the exact same information contained in the JSON file. In other words, I want to store that array itself inside the `people` array I just declared. How could I do this?

Comment: You can't do that using React. You have to use something that can read, create, update and delete a file like Node.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can. I've done it before, like 3 days ago, I just forgot how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about JSON data, and not JSON file.

Comment: Probably. What's the difference? You're probably right, but it's stored in jason filee

Comment: I import the data in my file, say 'import data from '../data/people.json''. Now, how do I copy over the data from 'data' into my new array?

Comment: You mean `const people = data;`? Or `import people from './data/people.json'`? or `const people = [...data]`? It's not clear to me what you're asking or what you're trying to do.

Comment: To clear everything up, I have a people.json file, that contains data as outlined above in my original question; it's an array of objects.

Now, I'm working in another file, called Items.js. In this file, I import the data using "import people from './data/people.json'. Now, I want to create a new array, say 'let new = []'. 

Now, I want to have the exact same array of objects in 'new'.

Comment: You have to export that JSON data from your `people.json` file, but I think you can't use export inside a `.json` file. Unless you have a literal json data on your code, then you can store your people array into that json data.

Comment: I'm telling you that I was able to get it to work. I don't need to export the data. There's a method using "push" somehow, just not sure the exact syntacx

Comment: You can do that with `const people = [...data]` but don't call it "new". "new" is a reserved word.

Comment: A good way to ask a question that involves asking how to transform data is to provide example input and expected output.  I recommend you edit your question and do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case try to use spread operator:

```
import people from './people.json';

const myPeople = [
    {"name": "Timothy", "age": 14}, 
    {...},
    {...}
];
people.people = [...myPeople];
```

`people.json` file

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "people": []
}
```